# Is it possible external microphone mute android phone?

Tags: android

I can mute the  external  microphone

```
 private AudioManager myAudioManager;

   myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   myAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it possible external microphone mute android phone?